# check android auto app log messages while connected to car

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-auto

I have a question on checking logs/debugging of android auto app when the mobile device is connected to the main Head Unit (car).

During apk installation on the Mobile device from the development machine 
using Android Studio, the logs can to checked using adb (Android Debug Bridge).
Since it is a development machine, the calls does not go into functions like *onCarConnectionCallbacks*.

So tried using DHU (Desktop Head Unit), but DHU is connected using adb forward socket connection, How to check for app log messages simultaneously?

And also how to check log messages or debug the app, when it is connected to the main Head Unit (Car), Should the adb be installed? (Here the mobile is not on development mode).

I am not able to find convincing answers online.
Please give your view on this.
Thanks

Comment: is the mobile device connected via a wifi network,or  bluetooth?

Comment: Mobile is connected to the Car via USB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the port forwarded for the DHU connection won’t affect the ADB streaming the logcat in another terminal. You can checkout the ADB documentation on how to [Connect to a device over Wi-Fi](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#wireless), and use a laptop to connect with since the usb connection will be used on the phone to connect to the car or DHU.

For the onConnectionCallbacks, those are still functional even when connecting to the DHU. Sounds like it might be a coding issue with registering the connection callback.

Comment: For the phone to get detected on the Head Unit, the developer mode should be OFF. So in this case the adb does not connect to the phone via WiFi

Comment: I think you're referring to the developer mode in the Auto app? Having the developer options enabled on the mobile device and usb debugging turned on shouldn't affect the phone being detected, or Auto projecting to the head unit.